# The last part of Weierstrass Theorem (1872)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** Let $a$ be an odd positive integer and $b$ a real number such that $0<b<1$. Suppose also that $ab>1+\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Let $f$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^k\cos[a^k\pi x].$$ Then $f$ is continuous and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ has a finite derivative at no point.

The last part of the proof is not clear to me. Without writing all the details, let $\{h_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n=0$. At the end of the proof it is proved that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{f(x+h_n)-f(x)}{h_n}\right|=\infty$$

> Why can I conclude from this that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$?

I found the following necessary condition for differentiability.

**Proposition.** Let $f$ be a real valued function on $(a,b)$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at some $x\in(a,b)$. Then for any two sequence $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that $a_n\uparrow x$ and $b_n\downarrow x$ as $n\to\infty$. we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}=f'(x).$$

> Can I use this condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$, because, by definition, a real valued function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if the limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
exists and is a **finite** real number.

Comment: Note, moreover, if the limit exists, then for any sequence $h_n\to 0$, we must get the same limit.